# Duty Free Shopping in Dubai during 2 Hour Layover

Tags: layovers, dubai, emirates, duty-free

I have a flight that has a 2 hour layover in DXB (Dubai). I would like to purchase something from the duty free and was wondering if I have the time to make the purchase and still make my connecting flight.

My connecting flight is also in the same terminal as my arrival, and the flights are on the same ticket.

Comment: actually 2 hours may not be enough given the *immense choice* of duty-free shops…

Comment: If there's something specific you want to get, try having a look at a map of the terminal. It could even be a good idea to have a look first anyway so you know what shops there are and what you want to get. Two hours may be enough time, but it may not be enough if you're browsing and taking your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your flights are on time and you've already checked in for your connecting flight, then **yes, easily**.  Dubai is (usually) quite efficient and organized, and even if you need to go through transit security, walk from gate to gate etc, you should still have more than one hour of free time.

Comment: Hi lambshaanxy, Thank you for the input. It really helps out